# Shrinking LVM Volumes

Tags: linux, lvm, mdadm, ext4, synology

We have a Synology RS3614rpxs NAS head containing (9) 3TB hard drives in a RAID 6 + 1 hot spare. The storage became exhausted and we added an expansion chassis where 5TB hard drivers were installed with the intention of creating a second array (also, RAID 6).

Synology appears to be use standard linux `md` to form RAID arrays with`LVM` on top to form volume groups (comprised of underlying `md` devices) and then logical volumes.

During the introduction of the expansion chassis, 3 of the disks were accidentally added to the first array (`md2`). A problem as we are losing usable space on the 5TB disks. The remaining disks appear to have been added to a second array (`md3`). `md3` appears to have been added to the existing volume group `vg1.`

Our objectives:

1. Remove `md3` from `vg1` and resize logical volume if necessary.
2. Destroy `md3` and make its disks available to be repurposed.

QUESTION: How might we best accomplish these objectives?

For Context:

**Output of "df -h"**

`Filesystem                Size      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/md0                  2.3G    637.9M      1.6G  28% /
/tmp                      1.9G    404.0K      1.9G   0% /tmp
/run                      1.9G      3.8M      1.9G   0% /run
/dev/shm                  1.9G         0      1.9G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/vg1/volume_3         2.4T      1.2T      1.2T  49% /volume3
/dev/vg1/volume_1         5.8T      2.9T      2.9T  49% /volume1
/dev/vg1/volume_2        10.7T     10.2T    443.5G  96% /volume2`

**Output of "lvdisplay"**

`--- Logical volume ---
  LV Name                /dev/vg1/syno_vg_reserved_area
  VG Name                vg1
  LV UUID                agGo1D-0811-miWz-ro0e-Nsvo-YdO9-XRJQY4
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Status              available
  # open                 0
  LV Size                12.00 MB
  Current LE             3
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     384
  Block device           253:0`


  `--- Logical volume ---
  LV Name                /dev/vg1/volume_1
  VG Name                vg1
  LV UUID                3oehZK-Bv5V-T1RL-MWfY-VQnh-tsrr-tXn3v9
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                5.86 TB
  Current LE             1536000
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     4096
  Block device           253:1`


 `--- Logical volume ---
  LV Name                /dev/vg1/volume_2
  VG Name                vg1
  LV UUID                3VMQE8-BG0Y-K0jC-Y2Rz-ID09-0dAs-XqTavU
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                10.74 TB
  Current LE             2816000
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     4096
  Block device           253:2`


  `--- Logical volume ---
  LV Name                /dev/vg1/volume_3
  VG Name                vg1
  LV UUID                mGs4IT-7QM8-PFF2-TD3O-SGzo-QaKp-33DrrW
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                2.47 TB
  Current LE             647706
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     4096
  Block device           253:3`

**Output of "vgdisplay"**

`--- Volume group ---
  VG Name               vg1
  System ID

  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        2
  Metadata Sequence No  9
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                4
  Open LV               3
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                2
  Act PV                2
  VG Size               40.88 TB
  PE Size               4.00 MB
  Total PE              10715889
  Alloc PE / Size       4999709 / 19.07 TB
  Free  PE / Size       5716180 / 21.81 TB
  VG UUID               9i82gX-6djB-1KC3-jbZK-nEJ2-9jJh-KvNgJp`

**Output of "pvdisplay"**

`pvdisplay
  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/md2
  VG Name               vg1
  PV Size               27.25 TB / not usable 3.56 MB
  Allocatable           yes 
  PE Size (KByte)       4096
  Total PE              7142441
  Free PE               2142732
  Allocated PE          4999709
  PV UUID               SmZrd0-jC5T-2QwU-Ecnh-PuY0-O9u6-sqDW1E`


  `--- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/md3
  VG Name               vg1
  PV Size               13.63 TB / not usable 1.62 MB
  Allocatable           yes 
  PE Size (KByte)       4096
  Total PE              3573448
  Free PE               3573448
  Allocated PE          0
  PV UUID               aQmMu2-gg8j-Be1T-IofO-bOuk-aL0s-ysiR6j`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

disclaimer: you should read lvm manual carefully and understand what each step does. however, there should be very little risk unless you encounter errors.

this is what I do usually i this case.

if there is a chance that someone else might do something to mess you up, you want to block any login while doing the maintenance (touch /etc/nologin etc. per your maintenance procedure and company policy).

pvmove /dev/md3 # make sure all used extents are moved away

pvs -o+pv_used # make sure that no extents are used in /dev/md3

vgreduce vg1 /dev/md3 # now remove the physical volume

Comment: Thank you. We recreated a similar scenario in a VM and tested your recommendation with success. We will report back with results from our production environment.